# RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag meta

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, html-to-pdf

I'm using iText in order to convert html into a pdf, but I keep getting a RuntimeWorkerException thrown at `parseXHtml`. Here's my code:

```
Document tempDoc = new Document();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(tempDoc, out);
tempDoc.open();
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, tempDoc, new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()));
tempDoc.close();
```

I'm not too familiar with the differences between HTML and XHTML, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I should handle this. [Here's the html source if it helps](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CeGAcp6t).

Comment: This sounds like an iText issue... Either because of not handling new html tags, or just a bug. Unfortuntely, there's probably no way around it, though maybe report it to the folks who manage iText?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you have a `<meta>` tag in the header that isn't closed which is valid in `HTML` but not `XHTML` which is what you are parsing it as. You need to close those, `<meta ... />`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, you have a `<meta>` tag in the header that isn't closed which is valid in `HTML` but not `XHTML` which is what you are parsing it as. You need to close those, `<meta ... />`

Comment: I ended up going with JTidy to convert to xhtml, and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to close all meta tags

```
<meta ... />
```

Comment: This actually has already been proposed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25493133/1729265)...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XMLWorkerHelper make sure you end image, breakpoint tag properly like />.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar error message -

`invalid nested tag body found, expected closing tag meta`

turned out the XHTML I was parsing had a `<script>` section at the bottom, that contained JS code, something like:

```
<script>
  function my_func(var) {
    ...
  }     
</script>
```

After removing that code (with simple string manipulations), I was able to get the `.parseXHtml` to work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

you have to close each and every tag.
example- in HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

is valid.

But in xhtml you have to use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
```

So close each and every tag in html (example meta tag, col tag, img tag etc).

Comment: You can also use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` as proposed by Chris in his answer.